# Change values in the same table before or after update trigger (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have table with 3 fields:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | FILE        |          STATUS             |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | my.exe      |           valid             |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | my.exe      |           invalid           |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3  | my.exe      |           invalid           |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4  | my.exe      |           invalid           |
--------------------------------------------------
```

This are some versions of one file. When I update status to "Valid" for any of them, I need all files with this name to change their status to "Invalid", 
except one updated:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | FILE        |          STATUS             |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | my.exe      |           invalid           |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | my.exe      |           invalid           |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3  | my.exe      |            valid            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4  | my.exe      |           invalid           |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I thought that it can be done in before update trigger:

```
create or replace trigger ChangeValid
  before update
  on mytable 
  for each row
declare

begin
   update mytable t set t.status = 'ivalid' where t.status = 'valid' and t.file = :new.file;

end ChangeValid;
```

But I kindly get ORA-04091.  Is the way to change values in this table with trigger?

Comment: you might be getting issue due to this `new.file;` check the datatype of the column follow this link to get more info https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=ora-04091-table-is-mutating-triggerfunction-may-not-see-it

Comment: Remove `declare` on your query

Comment: thanks for answers. It turns out that there is no way to update the data in the table automatically when changing the status value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the mutating table problem. The reason it happens is because you have written an UPDATE trigger which tries to execute an UPDATE statement on the same table. What do you think happens when you update those other rows? The trigger tries to fire, which means it executes the update statement, and so on recursively. Oracle short-circuits the nonsense by forbidding row level triggers which act on their own table and hurling `ORA-04091`.

You can solve this with a compound trigger:

```
create or replace trigger ChangeValid
for update on mytable compound trigger 

  type rec_nt is table of mytable%rowtype;
  recs rec_nt;

  before statement is 
  begin
    recs := rec_nt();
  end before statement;

  before each row is 
  begin
    null;
  end before each row;

  after each row is 
  begin
    recs.extend();
    recs(recs.count()).id := :new.id;
    recs(recs.count()).file_name := :new.file_name;
    recs(recs.count()).status := :new.status;
  end after each row;

  after statement is 
  begin

    for idx in 1 .. recs.count() loop
      if recs(idx).status = 'valid' then
          update mytable t
          set t.status = 'invalid'
          where t.file_name = recs(idx).file_name
          and t.status = 'valid'
          and t.id != recs(idx).id;
      end if;
    end loop;  

  end after statement;

end;
/
```

Note that **this trigger will run twice**: once for the row you updated and once for all the rows updated when the trigger runs. This is why we need the IF statement around the UPDATE in the `after statement` section. You also need to be careful that the UPDATE doesn't trigger recursion.

So if you have lots of records for `my.exe`  this could be an expensive way of implementing such logic. A better approach would be to have a PL/SQL API which updates the `status` of the current `valid` record and then applies the update to the target row.